# Change my app name, Show wrong bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, bundle

Before, my app's name was "Music" and my Bundle Identifier was named sophia.Music, I want to change my app name to a Chinese name like "音乐".

I changed my product name to "音乐" successfully,but my bundle Identifier changed to "sophia.----" ,can not show the right Chinese name!

Can anyone give some comments?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the details of iOS, but I do know that many systems only full Unicode character support in the user-facing parts of the app. The developer-side of things is often still expected to use English characters.

Comment: Ok,  I can change the bundle identifier manually in the plist.

Comment: Great! I recommend posting how you did it as an answer to your question, and accepting it, so that others can find this post useful. (You'll have to wait about 48 hours before you can do so.)

Comment: Follow the steps which are described at:- 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31874623/988169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to change it in your app's `.plist` file. Check out the image below:

[image]

Along with the changes to the `.plist` file, you'll need to change it in your project's **Target** -> **Info**. You'll find this when selecting the **main** project file in the Project Navigator. Once selected, choose target and then info. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @IamSophia if this, or any answer, has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. It helps people with the same problem understand that their problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the name of application you only need to go to plist file of the application and change the Bundle name property yo your desired name.