# My app display name is different with name in notification center

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, bundle

[image]My bundle is like sophia.music, but I changed my display name in Bundle display name to "音乐" and it works ok.
But, when I receive a notification, I check the notification on the notification center it still shows music. How can I change it? Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps to change the name:

1. Go to target settings
2. Select Build settings
3. Search "product name". It is available under Packaging header
4. Write your name here

Answer (score 0):

For changing app name set `CFBundleDisplayName` value in **info.plist** file:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>New app name here</string>
```

Name specified in this way would be displayed on device under the app icon.
Push notification service depends on app bundle id `CFBundleIdentifier`.
So you needn't regenerate certificates.

Comment: Just now my display name is different with my CFBundleIdentifier and When I receive a notification, it shows the last character of my CFBundleIdentifier, not my display name.  Should I change my CFBundleIdentifier, It will regenerate certificates

Comment: No, one word... And how to attach an image, I think a picture win thousand words!

Comment: please see the picture I attach